# Graph planarity definability clarification in literature?

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, planar-graphs, second-order-logic, presburger-arithmetic

Here it says planarity is definable in first order.

http://jgaa.info/accepted/recent/Brandenburg.pdf

Here it says planarity testing of graphs is not a first order property.

Refer https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/5233/lecture22.pdf

> Which of this is true?

1. Is planarity definable in first order?
2. If not what is the right way to define planarity in presburger?

Answer (score 4):

The two claims do not contradict.

Brandenburg's paper deals with "topological graphs": graphs drawn in the plane. Here, there is a built-in predicate $\chi(e,f)$ which is true if and only if edges $e$ and $f$ cross. Using this predicate, it is easy to determine if a graph drawing is a plane embedding: $\chi(e,f)$ must be false for all pairs of edges. (So, in other words, $\forall e\, \forall f\, \neg \chi(e,f)$.)

Note that even if a topological graph is non-planar, the underlying graph may still be planar, just badly drawn. For example, the graph below is planar, but the drawing is not, so Brandenburg considers this a nonplanar topological graph:

[image]

(Of course, if a graph is nonplanar, then any drawing of it will have crossings, so it will also be nonplanar as a topological graph.)

The model theory lecture, on the other hand, is actually talking about graphs, and does not have the luxury of a predicate $\chi$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the right way to define planarity in Presburger arithmetic if you may know in general graphs?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address most of your comments. For general graphs, I expect that the model theory lecture is correct and there is no first-order formula (which I assume is what you mean by Presburger arithmetic, as well).

Comment: I am thinking quantified logic statements? This seems relevant however unsure http://www.laas.fr/files/TSF/CourcelleExpoToulouse07.pdf.

Comment: @Turbo, Hanani-Tutte is the obvious way to express planarity in logic/arithmetic terms.